# prevent virtual directory contents from building in visual studio 2010 with iis express

Tags: visual-studio-2010, virtual-directory, iis-express

OK I have a website project within visual studio 2010 running under iis express. The nature of the website is such that an upload folder exists on a shared server and is accessed via a virtual directory within the website..

e.g.

```
web server one web root = d:\webs\mysite
web server one virtual dir = "documents" from \\sharedserver\uploadfolder
web server two web root = d:\webs\mysite
web server two virtual dir = "documents" from \\sharedserver\uploadfolder
```

This setup works just fine and as expected. In the production environment there is no execute access to the folder, it just allows read access to the files.

However, in the development environment I have an issue. I attach a virtual directory within visual studio and the website runs fine i.e. I can get website/document/blah.txt with no problems. However if a file such as a .rpt or .cs is uploaded, when I build the website within visual studio it trawls the virtual directory and detects files it thinks it could build and attempts to build them producing errors!

Is there a way for me to tell VS not to build the contents of the virtual directory?

Thanks

Comment: never found a solution to this. we stopped having the virtul directory in the dev environment for now.